# Change the size of pushed viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm presenting a ViewController which has UINavigationController. Is it possible to change the size of whole NavigationViewController just like when showing UINavigationViewController in UIPopOver and the size can be handled with setContentSizeInPopOver. Right now I'm not using UIPopover but I want to change the size of pushed view controller. Setting the frame of UINavigationController of pushed controller in viewDidload isn't helping.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the size of view controller that is to be presented u could use this one
   [How to present a modal view controller with custom size in center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048301/how-to-present-a-modal-view-controller-with-custom-size-in-center)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.

Try changing the frame of the view controller view's superview to desired frame just before presenting the navigation controller. Remove all the auto re-sizing masks of the view.